# android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView: null object reference only when app is opened via appium

Tags: android, appium

Are there any differences between running an app manually and using appium?

Because

It only happens when the app is started by appium. When app is installed and started manually, it runs normally without crashes.

If I want to automatically or manually display the one specific page the app crash “Unfortunately,… has stopped”

There are not any errors about it in appium logs. Only this exception in android monitor:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main   Process: ..., PID: 26842
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.mRecycler' on a null object
>   reference
>        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(RecyclerView.java:9580)
>        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.java:59)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:246)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:66)
>        at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6076)
>        at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:6037)
>        at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:22281)
>        at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6020)
>        at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:145)
>        at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
>        at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5974)
>        at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:22193)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.java:97)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateIcsImpl.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:192)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:432)
>        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.java:65)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:241)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:61)
>        at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5960)
>        at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5827)
>        at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:22132)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.java:122)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateIcsImpl.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:223)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:371)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:268)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:87)
>        at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5810)
>        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(RecyclerView.java:3206)
>        at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5789)
>        at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:22090)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.java:117)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateIcsImpl.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:217)
>        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:349)
>   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateComp

I use appium v1.6.5 (1.7.1) and Android 6.0 - 7.1 emulators

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Appium is using adb shell to install/launch app and for elements interactions it use UiAutomator / UiAutomator2 (depends on `AutomationName` capability you provided)

You can see it in Appium server logs:

install apk:

```
Running '/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb'
with args:["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.101:5555","shell","ls",
"/data/local/tmp/f0f1ea15bc776c996fddca878b00c589.apk"]
```

launch app:

```
 Running '/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb'
 with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.101:5555","shell","am","start",
 "-W","-n","<app_package>/<app_package>.launch.view.LaunchActivity","-S"]
```

waits for expected activity to be started:

```
Getting focused package and activity
Running '/Users/dmitry/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args:
["-P",5037,"-s","192.168.56.101:5555","shell","dumpsys","window","windows"]
Found package: <package> and fully qualified activity name : <activity_name>
```

finalize session creation:

```
New AndroidDriver session created successfully,
session 807d2f94-bf31-4107-87ca-848261a4ce15 added to master session list
```

So you can try the **same commands from terminal** and see if you can reproduce the crash